# Azure Data Studio - My result is rounded - SQL

Tags: sql, azure, rounding

Please help me, I dont know what happened with my Azure Data Studio, when calculating, the result is automatedly rounded.
In the below example, the result is 3.000 not 3.333 even though I declared @Cute is in decimal type

```
declare @Cute decimal(10,3) = 10/3
select @Cute
```

I have mentioned above

Answer (score 1):

The data type of the variable is irrelevant in this case, it's the target of the result - you're using literal values which are implicitly integers.

If you define at least one of the arguments to be a decimal type then data-type precedence will ensure the result is also a decimal:

```
declare @Cute decimal(10, 3) = 10.0 / 3;
select @Cute;
```

You could also use the definied variable as one of the arguments, the same data type precedence then applies, such as

```
declare @Cute decimal(10, 3) = 10;
set @cute = @cute / 3;
select @Cute;
```